# I made changes while on the wrong branch. I haven't committed yet. How do commit my changes to the intended branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

- I'm on branch A and made changes.
- The changes have not yet been added or committed.
- These changes are intended for branch B.

How do I go about adding and committing these changes to branch B?

Comment: If you haven't committed the changes yet, just `git checkout` the other branch.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! Go ahead and drop it as an answer and I'll mark it as such (otherwise I'll just answer my own question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends if you already committed the changes. Since you didn't commit the changes yet a `git checkout` should do the trick.